# How to calculate the Last IP address when the First IP address and the number of hosts are given

Tags: networking, ipv4

Can any one please help me to understand how to calculate the Last IP address.

Suppose I have 192.24.0.0 as my first IP address and given the number of hosts to be 2048. What will the last IP address.

I have calculated something like this. 
since 2048 is -2^11 we have 32-11 = 21 bits allocated for network address

But I am not sure how to calculate the last IP address.

Comment: Just add them up, with overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If **S** is the start address, and there are **N** contiguous addresses, then the last address will be **S + (N - 1)**.  No need to worry about overflow, since **S + N < 2^32**.